# How to configure FreeRADIUS for use with strongSwan group selection?

Tags: vpn, radius, strongswan, freeradius, eap

Building a VPN service with strongSwan, I need to distinguish between several groups of users where each group is assigned a certain subnet with certain permissions (i.e. "group x" has access only to a specific part of the local subnet, e.g. 192.168.10.10/32).

[The official strongSwan wiki only allows so-called "group selection"](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/EapRadius#Group-selection) with a RADIUS-server.

Now, according to the Wiki, there's two possibilities to gain group membership information; either by reading and interpreting the *class* attribute sent within a RADIUS-Accept response or by interpreting the *Filter-Id* attribute. The article does not highlight the (dis-)advantages of one method or the other.

Although I felt like using a RADIUS-server like FreeRADIUS was a bit of an overkill - I would have preferred a solution provided by strongSwan, some plugin etc - I set up and configured FreeRadius and that's where I got stuck.

I stuck with the first method (using the *class* attribute to send back group membership info).

In the configuration file for the rlm_files module (`freeradius/3.0/mods_config/files/authorize`) I set up Bob:

```
#
# The canonical testing user which is in most of the
# examples.
#
bob     Cleartext-Password := "hello"
        Reply-Message := "Hello, %{User-Name}"
#       Class := "myclass"
```

Authentication works without issues, the only thing that's missing is the *class* attribute. [This page lists all available FreeRADIUS attributes](https://freeradius.org/rfc/attributes.html). I looked for the *Class* attribute and tried to set a value (see above) which the daemon failed to read.

The file also clearly says

> Indented (with the tab character) lines following the first
>   line indicate the configuration values to be passed back to
>   the comm server to allow the initiation of a user session.
>   This can include things like the PPP configuration values
>   or the host to log the user onto.

Searching the net, [this post on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/939980/freeradius-return-user-groups-in-class-field) seems to use a similar approach but with another LDAP server. So far, there was no need for an LDAP server and that would mean another dependency or another service to rely on.

I also can't use cleartext passwords (like Bob does), instead, I'd prefer certificate-based authentication.

What's the right way to set up FreeRADIUS (and, if necessary, any other dependencies) for group-based policies? What possibilities do I have?

Comment: Is that last line of the `authorize` file commented out on purpose?

Comment: Yes, it is, because as I said, the daemon failed to read that line. @ecdsa

Comment: Did you try without the colon? (i.e. `Class = "myclass"`) That's at least how it's done in [this](https://www.strongswan.org/testing/testresults/ikev2/rw-eap-md5-class-radius/) test scenario (`users` file).

Comment: Uh, actually, I just figured out that it works with both with and without the colon. It just doesn't like `Reply-Message` and `Class` together. So when leaving out the `Reply-Message` attribute, it works fine. I wonder why though? In the example you provided, the `Class` attribute is also indented twice. I don't know if that's related. @ecdsa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the comma at the end of the `Reply-Message` line.

See the examples in the [users file man page](https://freeradius.org/radiusd/man/users.html).

Comment: You're so right, what a bummer. I missed that one. I got one more question though: Having moved to EAP-TLS for certificate based authentication, will the users file still be read and processed? Cause that doesn't seem to be the case right now. In other words, the only thing I need to accomplish is to specify the Class attribute based on the username. So I thought the easiest way to do so is by making use of the user file as above. Would you mind including that part in your answer as well?

Comment: That's really a separate question.  Happy to answer it if you ask it as a new question and post the link in the comments.

Comment: Please see the new question here: https://serverfault.com/questions/991017/how-to-configure-freeradius-with-eap-tls-and-group-based-authorization