# How to configure FreeRADIUS with EAP-TLS and group-based authorization?

Tags: radius, freeradius, eap

I configured FreeRADIUS to use EAP-TLS for certificate based authentication (self-signed certificates). Authentication works fine, except that I'd like to add group-based authorization.

More specifically, I need to use the `Class` attribute to be sent back to the NAS in the reply. This attribute will then be read and interpreted by the NAS as group membership information (e.g. `Class` = `myclass`).

Some background information: I use FreeRADIUS together with strongSwan; that's where the group membership info is interpreted.

I'm looking for a simple way to make FreeRADIUS aware of the groups. I tried to set the `Class` attribute within the the configuration file for the rlm_files module (`freeradius/3.0/mods_config/files/authorize`) which looked like this:

```
username     
            Reply-Message := "Hello, %{User-Name}",
            Class := "myclass"
```

I left the first line [empty because no "check item" is needed](https://freeradius.org/radiusd/man/users.html).

EAP-TLS authentication succeeds, however, the `Class` attribute is not appended to the reply.

I am not even sure whether FreeRADIUS does process the `user` (or `authorize`) file after the EAP-TLS authentication is done. I doubt that though.

Is there a simple way to specify the `Class` attribute based on the username (assuming there's multiple users and a few groups)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FreeRADIUS may not be processing the users file as it short-circuits the authorize section for most EAP packets.

You need to call the users file in the post-auth section using `files.authorize`, i.e.

```
Post-auth {
    files.authorize
}
```

`User-Name` can be set to anything and authorization will still succeed, so it's not good to use it when making policy decisions for EAP-TLS.

IIRC the certificate attributes get decoded and placed in the `&session-state:` list.

In which case you can do

```
Post-auth {
    update request {
        &request: += &session-state:[*]
    }
    files.authorize
}
```

Which should make all the attributes available for matching in the users file.  It should also print out which attributes were available in the debug output near the end of processing the authentication attempt.

Comment: Yup, you're right, thanks a lot. Though it's `files.authorize`, not `users.authorize`, but that's just a minor change (that was introduced in 3.0, I believe?!). Thank you